# Adding null to Set<Id> doesn't return an empty Set

Tags: apex, set, null

```
Set<Id> testIds = new Set<Id>();
testIds.add(null);

system.debug('testIds are ' + testIds);

system.debug('Size of the set is ' + testIds.size());
system.debug('isEmpty result is ' + testIds.isEmpty());
```

Here's what I get out of these debugs:

`testIds are {null}`

`Size of the set is 1`

`isEmpty result is false`

Perhaps I am incorrect but I thought that adding `null` to a `Set<Id>` should not add anything to the set. Instead it's converting the `null` to what looks like a String?

Is this the expected behavior or was there a change in APEX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have observed is expected behavior: `null` is a valid collection element, and containing it makes the collection non-empty.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I suppose I was completely wrong on this one.

Comment: It happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: So then that means that I should perform an `if statement` before adding a field to this set. For example `if (myObj__c.someField__c != null) { myIds.add(myObj__c.someField__c); }` otherwise it will think that the set holds an Id value.

Comment: More efficient to just remove it once at the end if you are using a set.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, but I swear I didn't have to do this before. My memory is playing tricks on me.